# App crashes when starting service in onClick method

Tags: android, service, permission-denied, wifi-direct

I am a newbie to android and I got a weird problem...

I am trying to modify the WifiDirectDemo provided by Google, more specifically, the demo offers us the freedom to choose a image I want to transfer but I just want it to transfer a specific image. The original code is as follows:

```
public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionInfoListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);

    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps                  
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
                }
            });
    return mContentView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User has picked an image. Transfer it to group owner i.e peer using
    // FileTransferService.
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    TextView statusText = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
    statusText.setText("Sending: " + uri);
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "Intent----------- " + uri);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uri.toString());
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
            info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
    getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

And it works totally fine. But after I move the code from onActivityResult method into onClick method, I got some errors in the runtime. Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps               
    String uristring = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A25";
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uristring);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
            info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
    getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

And the error code is as follows:

```
11-15 00:11:16.397: W/dalvikvm(18595): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41553b90)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[FileTransferService]
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595): Process: com.example.android.wifidirect, PID: 18595
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{42a042a8 18595:com.example.android.wifidirect/u0a77} (pid=18595, uid=10077) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1461)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2848)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4396)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2207)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1425)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1047)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at com.example.android.wifidirect.FileTransferService.onHandleIntent(FileTransferService.java:63)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 00:11:16.397: E/AndroidRuntime(18595):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Is there anyone can help?

Update:

I added the permission to the manifest, here is how the manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.android.wifidirect"
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

<!-- Google Play filtering --> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <activity
        android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Used for transferring files  after a successful connection -->
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".FileTransferService" />

</application>
```

And the app still crashes with the same error information.

But when I run the following code, no error occurs.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_detail, null);
   mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Allow user to pick an image from Gallery or other
                    // registered apps

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
                }
            });

    return mContentView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // User has picked an image. Transfer it to group owner i.e peer using

    String uristring = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A25";

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FileTransferService.class);
    serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uristring);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS,
            info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
    serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
    getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

So errors occur when I move the sequence of lines from onActivityResult to onClick. I just don't know what the situation is because actually I already added the MANAGE_DOCUMENT permission to the manifest and it keeps asking for permission. And without the permission in manifest, I can still access the image file if I put the code back to onActivityResult. Does anyone know why? Thank you so much!

Comment: i think you are missing some permission in manifest file

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am confused about this, if I put the String uristring = "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A25"; line in onActivityResult method, it works fine. No error about permission denial. And I also added the permission line you provided and that didn't change the situation. Exactly the same error information. Any idea about that?

Comment: Finally I bypass this problem by store and pick up images in "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(                         Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)" And it works. As I stated in the update, the origin problem is unsolved and I don't think it is because of the undeclared permission. Maybe it is because I am using Kitkat. [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837358/android-kitkat-securityexception-when-trying-to-read-from-mediastore) is another post that seems to be related to my problem .

Answer (score 0):

declare permission in your manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

Comment: I did declare the permission but it still doesn't work... Please see my updates. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**i think you are missing some permission in manifest file
Add this in your manifest file**

read this doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below permission in  your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

Comment: I did add the line in my manifest and still get the same error... Please refer to my updates for detailed information. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Did you find out what made it go right? I'm in exactly the same boat right now!!