# SecurityException when querying a ContentResolver in KitKat

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm writing a music player app. To find the music files on the device I'm using this:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = main.getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
```

However I'm getting a SecurityException:

10-08 12:17:03.060: E/AndroidRuntime(19130): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=19130, uid=10170 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

I have added the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. My previous development device ran Android 10 and this error didn't happen. My new one is version 19. Here is my manifest, showing the permissions.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.robclouth.thetechnomat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.robclouth.thetechnomat.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="org.puredata.android.service.PdService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can't find ANY information about this because all answers are "Add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission", which of course I already have. I'm at my wits end!

It appears to be similar to this, but the error message is different:
[Android KitKat securityException when trying to read from MediaStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837358/android-kitkat-securityexception-when-trying-to-read-from-mediastore)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the project since you've added the permission?

Comment: Yes, I had done. And restarted Eclipse. After updating Eclipse everything seemed to work fine, I think there was some version mismatch between the plugins that was calling problems. This is resolved now.